# Javascript: How to push key:pair values in Javascript Object which is already created

Tags: javascript, local-storage, form-data

My question Explanation:

I have a variable of type = new FormData()

It has some key pair values for example.

```
    const _CheckOutData = new FormData(); // Creating FormData object to send mulitpart data
   _CheckOutData.append('Name', this._CheckOutForm.get('name').value);//Appending values to the 
   _CheckOutForm varibale from FormGroup
   _CheckOutData.append('Street', this._CheckOutForm.get('street').value);//Appending values to the 
   _CheckOutForm varibale from FormGroup
  _CheckOutData.append('City', this._CheckOutForm.get('city').value);/
```

I want to save these values in localStorages. when I directly save _ChechOutData to local storage its empty. Snippet of this function is

```
 SaveFormDataToLocalStorage(_CheckOutData){
     localStorage.setItem('_CheckOutData',JSON.stringify(_CheckOutData));
  }
```

So getting empty local Storage. I tried a different apporach which actually work but as my Question is I want to push the values from the _CheckOutData (Type FormData) into new object. here is the snippet

```
 _CheckOutData.forEach((key,value)=>{
       let Value=key;
       let Key=value;
       let TemporaryCart={
       [Key]:Value
     }
      this._CartCheckOutData.push(TemporaryCart);
   })
```

So I am Successfully getting all and values and save them into TemporaryCart (type Object). But the Problem is if there are 5 values it is created 5 object in the Array.But I want to creat one Object with 5 values in it.

My Actual Result:

```
 [{Name: "Fazi"}, {Street: "10570 S De Anza Blvd, Cupertino, CA 95014, United States"}]
```

But What I want

```
 [
     {
      Name:"Fazi",
      Street:"xyz 123",
      .
      .
      .
      .
      And So One
     }
 ]
```

Please Help me community: Regards Abdul Rehman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this one to change formdata in object

```
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    object[key] = value;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
```

Comment: let me try it bro

Comment: Great Bro its working. bro can you explain it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, forEach funciton iterate over key an value of formdata. In this i have directly changed objects value by using object[key] and assigned it the value against that key. Then i json stringify it to be convert object into json.

Comment: so bro I dont need to JSON.stringyfy(json) while saving it into local Storage

Comment: Brother I want to be in your circle can you please share me any social media platform where I can take your advises

Comment: yeah sure, Follow me on Instagram! Username: renu_yd
https://www.instagram.com/renu_yd?r=nametag

Comment: please Accept My request on instagram. its fazi1live

Answer (score 0):

A FormData object will look more like an array of arrays than an actual object. That's basically why a FormData object can have more entries with the same key.

So instead of trying to convert the FormData into an object into JSON, try to turn in into an array.

```
const formDataToJSON = formData => {
  const entriesArray = [...formData];
  return JSON.stringify(entriesArray);
}
```

This will first turn the FormData object into an array that looks like this (before the JSON step):

```
[
  ["Name", "Fazi"],
  ["Street", "xyz 123"],
]
```

This format will keep all the values in the FormData intact, as you could have multiple keys with the same name.

Reversing the process can be done as well.

```
const JSONtoFormData = json => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const entriesArray = JSON.parse(json);

  for (const [name, value] of entriesArray) {
    formData.append(name, value);
  }

  return formData;
};
```

Comment: Amazing Explanation. Thanks bro Helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the keys of the object this way:

```js
some_list = []
some_object = {}
some_object['new_key_1']=123
some_object['new_key_2']='abc'

some_object

some_list.push(some_object)
```

will give you

```
> some_object
{ new_key_1: 123, new_key_2: 'abc' }
> some_list
[ { new_key_1: 123, new_key_2: 'abc' } ]
```

Because you want to copy one object into another you could also try alternatively:

```js
> target_object = {...some_object, and_another_key:'123.123'}
{ new_key_1: 123, new_key_2: 'abc', and_another_key: '123.123' }
```

good luck!

Comment: Bro this method is looking really smiple and precise let me try it

Comment: No bro same issue one Array with multiple objects.